# Problem with a question requiring me to prove a derivative

Tags: derivatives

I have been staring at the following question for an hour now, but the answer simply does not make sense to me…

The question asks: please prove that if a is a constant, then...
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmcJa.png)

My problem with the answer is that I do not understand where the first ay comes from in the numerator in ay(x+Δx)
[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkSTC.png)

Could somebody please help out?

Thanks!

Yair

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Note:  we are working with functions of the variable $x$.  We assume $y=y(x)$ is one such.  If so, we can define another, $f(x)$ by $f(x)=a\times y(x)$.  Thus, for example, $f(x+\Delta x)=a\times y(x+\Delta x)$ and so on.  Just follow this through and compute $f'(x)$ in terms of $\frac {dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, José

It was my first time posting, so I wasn't aware...